# Which Shiva mantras can be chanted without initiation?

Tags: shiva, mantras

I have heard that *nama japa* can be chanted without initiation. If this is true, then can someone advise such mantras?

Comment: Nama japa and mantra japa are not the same. Mantras have to be accepted from a Guru. And nama japa for Shiva will be the chant "shiva, shiva, ....."

Comment: Ohhh okay. So nama japa is literally just saying the name of the deity

Comment: Yes .. nama means name.

Comment: @Rickross Can someone do nama japa without purascharana? Just sitting with or without mala and chanting the name of god and remembering the deity..Are there conditions for nama japa like there are many conditions for mantra japa?

Comment: Daily Nama Japa is also done .. not necessary to do it only for Puruscharana .. although it is always better to keep count of the Japa whether Nama or Mantra Japa. @LSSJBroly

Comment: Oo..Thanks for clarifying....It means that is also counted in nama japa...Actually I asked this doubt becoz I've seen many people (especially elders) in temples and other places where they just chant the name of god without purascharana. Some with mala and some without...